# how to dynamically add an new input field on "keydown" using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to have a new `input field` dynamically generated whenever I type on the last `input field` in the form.

This is my **HTML** codes

```
<form method = "POST" action="test2.php" >

<input type="text" name='text1'>
```

so when i `input` text in the `input field` above, a new `input field` should dynamically be generated.

For example.

```
<input type="text" name='text2'>
```

and if I `input` text again in the newly generated `input field`, a new `field` should be generated right after it as well, I want a `</br>` gap between these inputs.

```
</br><input type="text" name='text3'>
```

Bellow the `inputs`, there should be a `submit` `button`. When I click this `button` the entire `form` (including all the dynamically generated `input fields`) should be sent to the database using `Ajax` and `PHP`.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: I think what you are asking for is this:
The user completes an entry. The field name is incremented by one and the next <tr> appears. This continues until the user stops making entries. How do you know when they have stopped. Will there be a submit button?

Comment: sry if u not understand, yes like Len_D say, thy have button save too, but i just dont understand how make repeating useing javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but you might like something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $txt=new Array();

 $(function(){

     $('#go').on('click',function(){

         console.log($('form').serialize());

         })
     $('body').on('keydown','.last',function(){

         $('.last').removeClass('last');

         $('#go','body').before('</br><input class="last" type="text" name="text'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value="'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'"></br>');
         })
     })

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
<input  class="last"  type="text" name='text1' value="no text">

<input id="go" name="" type="button" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITS:** I added a `<form>`  for you, and some codes to see what data we are sending when the button is clicked. See the result is your browser `console`.  i.e: firebug or others *shortcut key usually: (F12)*

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3jLbm9sp/1/

Comment: See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jLbm9sp/1/

Comment: Great, enjoy programming.!!

Comment: sry for ask u again,when i put button in down and make form post for testing echo text1-text3 , why only text1 appear? and another Undefined index: text2-text3?

Comment: Please elaborate... Can you rephrase the Question?

Comment: sry if u not understanding, so I want to create a form that will fill in the data will be saved into the databases with the submit button, like a the table you created, so when press the save button will save all data on the contents into databases, its already correct but when i try input with 3 table(text1-text2-text3) only text1 save and another undefined(text2-text3)

Comment: Try again, I have edited the Code.... Open your console to See the result.... thanks

Comment: sorry bother you, and thank you for you're commentnya it is correct Thank you very much

Comment: Sure... dont hesitate to let me know incase you need further help.....[Enjoy Programming!!]

Comment: sry for ask again, but can u check this too please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228378/how-to-pass-php-in-javascript-the-autocomplete-in-the-dynamically-add