# how to pass php in javascript, the autocomplete(autosuggestion) in the dynamically add?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

sorry for bad english.
so i want try make to dynamically add an new input field on key down with using autocompelete(auto suggestion) for evey new dynamically add. so every add an new input field will be have autocompelete(suggestion) too.but i confuse in javascript ,this all my coding

```
<html>
    <head>
        <form method = "POST" action="text.php" >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link href="css/inputpo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#code1").autocomplete({
                source: 'autosuggest.php',
                select:function(event, ui){
                            $('#descrip1').val(ui.item.descrip1);
                            $('#color1').val(ui.item.color1);
                            $('#type1').val(ui.item.type1);
                            $('#qty1').val(ui.item.qty1);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>           
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $txt=new Array();

            $(function(){
                $('#go').on('click',function(){
                    console.log($('form').serialize());
                })

                $('body').on('keydown','.last',function(){
                    $('.last').removeClass('last');
                    $('#go','body').before(
                    '<table><tr><td><input class="last" type="input" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value="<?php echo $code1; ?>"></td><td><input  class="last" type="text" id="descrip" name="descrip'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value=""></td><td><input  class="last" type="text" id="type" name="type'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value=""></td><td><input class="last" type="text" id="color" name="color'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value=""></td></tr></table>');           
                })
            })
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if($_GET) {
    $code1      = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code1'] : '';
    $descrip    = isset($_POST['descrip1']) ? $_POST['descrip1'] : '';
    $color      = isset($_POST['color1']) ? $_POST['color1'] : '';
    $type       = isset($_POST['type1']) ? $_POST['type1'] : '';
    $qty        = isset($_POST['qty1']) ? $_POST['qty1'] : '';
    }
    $code1="";
    ?>
        <div class="isi">

                <table height="51" border="0" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td width="99" align="center" label for="suggestionbox">
                        <div align="center">Code Product</div></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">Description</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">Type</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">Color</div>
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="code1" name='code1' value="<?php echo $code1;?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="descrip1" name='descrip1' value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="type1" name='type1' value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="color1" name='color1' value="">
                </td>

              </tr>
            </table>
                <input id="go" name="" type="submit" /></td>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's almost correct for autocomplete(auto suggestion) in dynamically just error in Javascript in here

```
    <td><input class="last" type="input" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value="<?php echo $code1; ?>"></td>
```

if value=" " its correct but cant give autocomplete(suggestion) for second field, supposed value is `"<?php echo $code1; ?>"`but its will view in field is `"<?php echo $code1; ?>"` anybody can help me??

Comment: its like this for (autosuggestion) try input AB but cant add new field still have error http://jsfiddle.net/3jLbm9sp/1/ and this for dynamically but cant autosuggetion http://jsfiddle.net/3jLbm9sp/1/  , can't dynamically and autosuggetion..

Answer (score 0):

$code1=""; is after the if condition so whatever the value is coming from post it in `$code1      = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code1'] : '';` it will again assigned at the end `$code = "";` which make it empty every time.

So do it like this

```
<?php
    $code1="";
    if($_GET) {
    $code1      = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code1'] : '';
    $descrip    = isset($_POST['descrip1']) ? $_POST['descrip1'] : '';
    $color      = isset($_POST['color1']) ? $_POST['color1'] : '';
    $type       = isset($_POST['type1']) ? $_POST['type1'] : '';
    $qty        = isset($_POST['qty1']) ? $_POST['qty1'] : '';
    }
    ?>
```

now it first asign velue "" to $code1 and if $_GET has value new value is been assigned to it

or you can add else and put it in there

Comment: no its already correct, so when i try input for first field its will be add new field, for first field already have autocompelete and add dynamically(for second field), but when i try add text for second field it's no have autocompelete. when i check the failed is in Javascript dynamically because value is "$code1", when value="" can add new field but cant autocomplete, btw value must $code1 for autocomplete second field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a session + ajax. I'm not 100% sure if it will suit your needs or not:

**page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link href="css/inputpo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form method = "POST" action="text.php" id="masterform">
    <div id="adder">Add</div><div id="delete">Clear</div>
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <input id="go" name="" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function AddFormRow(IdElem,Func)
            {
                $("#"+IdElem).html("Loading...");

                if(Func == 1)
                    Qfunc   =   'command=true';
                if(Func == 0)
                    Qfunc   =   'command=false';

                $.ajax({
                        url: "page2.php?"+Qfunc,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                                $("#"+IdElem).html(result);
                            }
                    });
            }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            AddFormRow('loader',1);
            $("#adder").click(function() {
                    AddFormRow('loader',1);
                });
            $("#delete").click(function() {
                    AddFormRow('loader',0);
                });
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();


     if(isset($_GET['command']) && $_GET['command'] !== 'true')
         unset($_SESSION['myform']);

     $_SESSION['myform'][]  =   1;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['myform']); $i++) { ?>

        <table height="51" border="0" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td width="99" align="center" label for="suggestionbox"><div align="center">Code Product</div></label></td>
                <td><div align="center">Description <?php echo $i; ?></div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Type <?php echo $i; ?></div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Color <?php echo $i; ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input  class="last"  type="text" id="code<?php echo $i; ?>" name='code<?php echo $i; ?>' value="code<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                <td><input  class="last"  type="text" id="descrip<?php echo $i; ?>" name='descrip<?php echo $i; ?>' value=""></td>
                <td><input  class="last"  type="text" id="type<?php echo $i; ?>" name='type<?php echo $i; ?>' value=""></td>
                <td><input  class="last"  type="text" id="color<?php echo $i; ?>" name='color<?php echo $i; ?>' value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thx for comment,it's not like that so first i want make dynamically add like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215680/how-to-dynamically-add-an-new-input-field-on-keydown-using-jquery and it's already good, next i want give autocomplete (suggestion) for every field, so when i try it's wrong because failed in here '<td><input class="last" type="input" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value="<?php echo $code1; ?>"></td>' in value="<?php echo $code1; ?>"